# How to convert a time format to Int, do some calculations with it and convert it back to a time format?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, userdefaults

I am trying to convert the current time to an Int (without the AM/PM addition) and doing calculations with it. For instance, compare it to an older time and calculate the difference, then show the difference in hours:minutes. But I am really struggling here.

Getting the time:

```
func getTime() -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .long
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())
    return dateString
}
```

I'd like to remove the AM/PM here.

Saving time to UserDefaults:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.currentTime, forKey: "startTime")
```

Getting the saved time and current time and do some calculations here:

```
let startTime = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "startTime")
let currentTime = getTime()
let timeDiff = currentTime - startTime
```

Obviously this doesn't work because it's all strings. I know how to convert a string of integers to int: Int(getTime()) ?? 0 for instance, but as long as I cannot remove the AM/PM this all doesn't work of course.

What can I do or am I making this more difficult than it should be?

Comment: Yes you are over complicating things, no need to involve strings in this. Here is one way to convert the date to a double, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779963-timeintervalsince1970. But you should really read up on the date and times classes that are available, maybe there’s even a better solution for you. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dates_and_times

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

`Date` provides an API which returns the number of seconds (as `TimeInterval` / `Double`) since Jan 1, 2001.

Save this value to `UserDefaults`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, forKey: "startTime")
```

And read ist

```
let startTimeInterval = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "startTime")
let startTime = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: startTimeInterval)
let currentTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
let timeDiff = currentTime - startTime
```

and display it with the appropriate formatter

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
let timeString = string(from: timeDiff)
print(timeString)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better not do Date calculations in Int, use [DateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponents) instead. it provides `Int` values for all date components (day, hour,..). For specific string formats (e.g no am/pm) use `DateFormatter`.